# Flutter MainApp as StatefulWidget leads to problems

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I'm afraid I've totally lost my way as a beginner with my Flutter app. I come from the .NET c# world. The app is supposed to have multiple pages that can be switched back and forth between. For this purpose I have included a `PageView`.

However, I need to be able to pass data from one page to another. For this I have introduced a property `currentArticleList` and therefore had to convert the `MainApp` into a `StatefulWidget`. I think this was a mistake, because now the `AppBar`, for example, can't access the theme colors anymore. Also, I've read in several places that this is generally a bad practice, because it will always redraw the whole app.

The `MainApp` itself will never access the `currentArticleList`, by the way.

How can I fix the theme color accessing problem? Can I leave it as a `StatefulWidget`, or is there a better, more flutter-like solution? I've added some comments to the source code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_lss/pages/article_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter_lss/pages/loading_overlay.dart';
import 'package:flutter_lss/pages/scan_number.dart';
import 'package:flutter_lss/data/article.dart';

enum AppPage {
  scanNumber,
  articleList,
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  List<Article> currentArticleList = List.empty(); // This is the reason the MainApp must be stateful. Isn't there a better way to do this?
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          // ...
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: LoadingOverlay(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, // this returns the default colors instead of the ones set by me
            foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
            title: const Text('My App'),
          ),
          body: PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: [
              PageScanNumber(onArticlesFetched: _handleFetchedArticles),
              PageArticleList(articles: currentArticleList, onScanningComplete: _handleScanningComplete),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleFetchedArticles(List<Article> articles) {
    setState(() {
      currentArticleList = articles;
    });
    _animateToPage(AppPage.articleList);
  }

  void _handleScanningComplete() {
    _animateToPage(AppPage.scanNumber);
  }

  void _animateToPage(AppPage page) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      page.index,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: To pass data from one page to another, you might want to use a [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) approach. I personally recommend Riverpod

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Would that solve my problem? Looks like a little bit of overkill for this small app. At least to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read theme within the same context you've provided. You can liftup the MaterialApp(context) so that it can get your provided theme data. Or just wrapping with Builder widget will work fine `home: Builder(builder: (context) => LoadingOverlay(....),)`.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            // ...
            ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

I would prefer creating widget for app and home separately.

Comment: Thank you! That works! Would you say that my overall approach is good? Or is there a more preferable way to transfer data from widget to widget?

Comment: For theming, you can check out [flex_color_scheme](https://pub.dev/packages/flex_color_scheme)